# Identify which table entry I clicked

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am trying to create a dynamic table which should have as entry in one of it's columns a button which launched a bootstrap modal. I don't know how to check which button was clicked and how to fill up the table. Sorry, I don't have really much experience with markups. Here is  what I have so far:

```
div.span12
table.table.table-hover
    thead
        tr
            th Patient Name
            th Phone Number
            th History
    tbody
        each pat in patients
            tr
                td #{pat.name}
                td #{pat.phone}
                if (0<pat.history.length)
                    td #{pat.history[0]}
                else
                    td No history

a.btn(data-toggle="modal", href="#myModal") Launch
div.modal.hide(id="myModal")
    .modal-header
        button(type="button", class="close", data-dismiss="modal") x
        h3 Modal Header
    .modal-body
        p One fine body...
    .modal-footer
```

So I would like to substitute the `td #{pat.history[0]}` with something (unique id?) on which if I click I can pop up the modal and show the related `patient` data. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but it seems to me a bit ugly. If there is another cleaner one, please tell me:

```
            each pat,key in patients
            tr
                td #{pat.name}
                td #{pat.phone}
                if (0<pat.history.length)
                    td 
                        span(onclick='console.log(#{key})') #{pat.history[0]}
                else
                    td No history
```

Like this I can associate the element from my array of patients to the row it was clicked and I can pop up the modal with the desired content, but is it OK to use it like this?